# Understanding how pattern matching works in Ruby 2

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

I don't know how pattern matching works in Ruby 2.

I have the following value, `targetfilename = /mnt/usb/mpeg4Encoded.mpeg4`

My pattern matching if-else is thus:

```
if (targetfilename.match(/^\//))
  puts "amit"
else 
  puts "ramit"
```

The output is `ramit`.

I don't understand how this pattern matching works though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if targetfilename.match(/^V/)
  puts "amit"
else
  puts "ramit"
end

# result:
# "amit"
```

Why is this?  This is because `targetfilename.match(/^V/)` outputs a [Matchdata](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) object (click on the link for a full description of this object).  This is an object that contains all of the information that is in the "matching".  If there is no match, no MatchData object is returned, because there's nothing to return.  Instead, you get `nil`.

When you use `if`, if it tries to compare a `nil`, it treats it the same way as `false`.

Basically, any "actual" value (besides `false`) is treated the same way as `true`.  Basically, it's asking

```
if (there's anything here)
  do_this
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Again, let me reiterate:

If the thing after `if` is either **false** or **nil**, the if statement resolves to the "else".
If it's *anything else*, it resolves as if it had gotten a "true" statement.

---

**Regular Expressions**

`/^V/` is what is called a "Regular Expression"; the `//` is a Regexp literal the same way that the `""` is a String literal, and Regexps are represented by the Regexp class the same way that strings are represented by the String class.

The actual "regular expression" is what's between the slashes -- `^V`.  This is saying:

- `^`: the start of a string
- `V`: a capital letter V

So, `/^V/` will match any cases of the capital letter "V" at the beginning of a string.

What else can you put in a regular expression?  What are the special characters?  Try this [regexp cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)

Also, some great tools:

- [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) -- enter in your regular expression, and then a same text, and see what matches.
- [Strfriend](http://strfriend.com/) -- enter in a regular expression and see it "visually" represented.

Comment: thanks JUSTIN ...but justin what i want to no is how (/^\//) is working actully i already known abt the fact like matchdataobject and nil value